# Why is flutter app not running on virtual device created with android studio

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to run flutter app. I have installed flutter, android studio and set all my settings as per my knowledge. When I am trying to run the app on virtual device created with android studio created with flutter , I'm getting this we

[enter image desc[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Nr3.png)ription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywkzK.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjxYk.png)

Comment: run flutter doctor from terminal/powershell

Comment: can you run it with `--info`?